# @angular/service-worker not working when offline

Tags: angular, angular-cli, service-worker

I never got the service worker from Angular Mobile Team to work properly and at this point I guess I forgot to enable something, because it never worked since the initial release. Even if it installs and run on Google Chrome (smartphone & desktop) when I go offline it doesn't work anymore, also it randomly crashes after updates.

There is no documentation on how to set it up. So here is how I did it:

- `ng new test-service-worker`
- `npm install @angular/service-worker`
- in `.angular-cli.json`, I add `"serviceWorker": true`
- `npm build --prod`, output `ngsw-manifest.json` `sw-register.b73048fe3d9f8a1e7ae5.bundle.j`s and `worker-basic.min.js`. So everything seems ok
- https://test-service-worker-97321.firebaseapp.com/ the SW installs
- If I go offline, wait an hour for cache to expire (or simply disable cache), I get a `failed to load` error, no matter the device I use.

---

**The generated `dist` directory:**

[image]

---

**The generated `ngsw-manifest.json`:**

[image]

---

**The service worker installed and running:
Test available https://test-service-worker-97321.firebaseapp.com/**

[image]

---

When I set the chrome devtools options to `Offline` and `Disable cache` the service worker doesn't load content anymore. A good example of how it is supposed to work is Twitter, their web app works when `Offline` and `Disable cache` are checked.

[image]

NB: I created a few apps before with service workers, and they worked properly on Chrome. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to test your app in offline mode with an explicit mentioning of `index.html`. I checked https://test-service-worker-97321.firebaseapp.com/index.html - it works fine.

If you wish your app to work in offline without index document mentioned (and for all other routes), you have to set up [route redirection](https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/tree/master/service-worker/worker#feature-route-redirection-to-indexhtml)

See [the example](https://github.com/webmaxru/pwa-workshop-angular/blob/step3/ngsw-manifest.json). This custom `ngsw-manifest.json` will be merged with auto-generated one during the build.

Comment: but now, since the ngsw-manifest.json is not available anymore (Angular v5), how would I define the routes? Or do I not need to anymore?

Comment: @Nadine ngsw-manifest.json changed its name and format (slightly) and the way it's processed - now it's ngsw-config.js: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config

Comment: Is "routing" then still existing as part of the config or not?

Comment: @Nadine: Not. Now we have a way more flexible config with assetGroups for app shell and dataGroups for API calls (and other runtime requests)

Answer (score 1):

With Maxim's help, I followed the same path as asking person, managed to add offline capability to the existing static web and deploy it on [Firebase](https://joanne-lee.firebaseapp.com/home). The [custom manifest](https://github.com/bob-lee/ng-joanne-lee/blob/master/ngsw-manifest.json) on root folder should look like below, they will eventually be merged with autogenerated manifest:

```
{
  "routing": {
    "index": "/index.html",
    "routes": {
      "/": {
        "prefix": false
      },
      "/home": {
        "prefix": false
      },
      "/work": { // any routes starting with '/work'
        "prefix": true
      }
    }
  },
  "external": {
    "urls": [
      {
        "url": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```