# Angular 5 PWA not loading in Offline mode

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have created freshly a PWA with Angular CLI using the following versions:
Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 8.8.1
Angular: 5.2.5

My problem: When I go offline I just get a blank page. The service worker does not load any assets from the cache.
If I manually stop and start it then it will start to work for a short time.

Haven't changed anything this is what the cli generated.

Configuration I am using:
ngsw.json:

```
{ 
  "index": "/index.html", 
  "assetGroups": [{ 
    "name": "app", 
    "installMode": "prefetch", 
    "resources": { 
      "files": [ "/favicon.ico", "/index.html" ], 
      "versionedFiles": [ "/*.bundle.css", "/*.bundle.js", "/*.chunk.js" ] 
    } 
  }, { 
    "name": "assets", 
    "installMode": "lazy", 
    "updateMode": "prefetch", 
    "resources": { "files": [ "/assets/**" ] } 
  }] 
}
```

and app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any suggestion where I could start to look for a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you have any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish your app to work in offline without index document mentioned (and for all other routes), you have to set up router redirection.

You can take a look at this SO answer:
[@angular/service-worker not working when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029667/angular-service-worker-not-working-when-offline)